# How to iterate on specific group on win cmd bat from LOCALGROUP

Tags: batch-file, cmd

#1

```
for %%r in ("users" "admin" "guest" ) do (
 IF ( NET LOCALGROUP | FIND /i %%r > nul ) (
     netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:%i%/ user=%%r
 )
)
```

#2

```
for %%r in ("users" "admin" "guest" ) do (
 NET LOCALGROUP | FIND /i %%r > nul && goto GroupExists
goto NextGroup
:GroupExists
echo do somethings ...
:NextGroup
)
```

I try 2 ways without success.
#1 I can't add the `IF` and make specific commands only for the 3 groups on my list.
I want to open a specific port for these group only

I also try #2, but the goto in for loop cancel the loop  :-(

Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you really want to do? The command `net LOCALGROUP` just lists the local user groups as you can see on running this command in a command prompt window. You can run `net LOCALGROUP Administrators` (with English Windows) to see the accounts which belong to local group `Administrators`. Run in cmd window `net localgroup /?` for a brief help on available options.

Comment: We need to know what you're trying to achieve, because in a basic Windows system, I'd expect to see at least these lines from `%__AppDir__%net.exe LocalGroup` match those three case insensitive `%__AppDir__%find.exe` strings: `*Administrators`, `*Distributed COM Users`, `*Guests`, `*Hyper-V Administrators`, `*Performance Log Users`, `*Performance Monitor Users`, `*Power Users`, `*Remote Desktop Users`, and `*Remote Management Users`, and `*Users`.

Comment: #1: that's not how `if` works. See `if /?`. #2: labels are not allowed within a loop and each `goto` will break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File 'C:\src\t\Get-ThreeGroups.ps1
```

=== Get-ThreeGroups.ps1

```
Get-LocalGroup -Name @('guests','users','administrators') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|
    & doit.exe $_.Name
```

If you do not want to have a .ps1 file, you could use this in a .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-LocalGroup -Name @('guests','users','administrators') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|" ^
        "& doit.exe $_.Name"
```

Comment: thanks, I preferred to do it on bat cmd but if I will not succeed to fix the condition on bat com localgroup i will try the ps .

Q : What does it mean the last part  ^ "& doit.exe $_.Name" ?

There is any way to add IF condition and run a command that open port like on the original message only when a group exists on the machine ?

Comment: @orenga, the `& doit.exe` would be your "specific commands." Groups that do not exist will not be passed down the pipeline to your specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

for the next generation, this is the answer :

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
for %%r in ("users" "admin" "guest" ) do (
 NET LOCALGROUP | FIND /i %%r > nul && CALL :HandlePort %%r
)
GOTO END
:HandlePort
ECHO %*
SET /a i=8090
:loop
IF %i%==8095 ( EXIT /B 0 )
REM echo This is port %i%.
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:%i%/
netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:%i%/ user=%*
SET /a i=%i%+1
GOTO LOOP
EXIT /B 0
:END
```